# Select a cell in a specific Column only to print C#

Tags: c#

I have a grid-view in the form as below:  grid-view name is dgvItem.

```
╔════╦═════════╦══════════╦══════╦═════════╗
║ ID ║ STOCKNO ║ ITEMNAME ║ COST ║ COSTQTY ║
╠════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════╬═════════╣
║ 1. ║ mx01    ║ LIMNO    ║ 500  ║ 1       ║
╠════╬═════════╬══════════╬══════╬═════════╣
║ 2. ║ my01    ║ DEMO     ║ 150  ║ 2       ║
╚════╩═════════╩══════════╩══════╩═════════╝
```

This is my code which I tried:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString("NAME          : " + dgvItem.CurrentRow.Cells[2].ColumnIndex, new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(25, 400));
```

I should be able to print select any cell from the `ITEMNAME` column only:

- If I select the "LIMNO" cell the output must be "LIMNO"
- If I select the "DEMO" cell the output must be "DEMO"

I am getting as 4 as an output which is wrong please help

Comment: You're drawing `ColumnIndex` which is an integer, maybe you meant `DrawString("NAME : " + dgvItem.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString()`?

Comment: Perhaps off-topic, but fonts are unmanaged objects; you should call `f = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular)` in your  `BeginPrint` or something, use `f` in your `PrintPage`, and `f.Dispose` in your `EndPrint`.